# How to access custom headers in controller constructor when unit testing

Tags: c#, class, constructor, initialization

My problem is that I have a web api controller base class that I need to write tests for. I am having trouble doing this because my controller base class constructor needs to use the "accessToken" request header value, which is still NULL when the constructor goes off when the class is instantiated from the unit test as follows:

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.Headers.Add("accessToken", "some token value");
BaseController controller = new BaseController()
 {
   Request = request,
   Configuration = new HttpConfiguration()
 };
```

Here is the code for BaseController:

```
   public class BaseController : ApiController
    {
        public UserInformation CurrentUser { get; set; }
        readonly private IDatabase dataBase;

        public BaseController(IDatabase db = null) : base()
        {
            if (db == null)
                dataBase = new Database();
            else
                dataBase = db;
            ReadUserFromToken();
        }

        private void ReadUserFromToken()
        {
            // verify that the request contains an access token header
            if (Request.Headers.Contains("accessToken") == false)
                throw new AuthorizationException("Authorization token is missing");

            // get the request header containing the user information
            string loginToken = Request.Headers.GetValues("accessToken").FirstOrDefault();
            if (loginToken != null)
            {
                CurrentUser = new UserInformation();
                if (CurrentUser.LoadFromDatabaseByAccessToken(loginToken, dataBase) == false)
                {
                   throw new AuthorizationException("Authorization token is not valid");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a different way to instantiate my class so that the request is populated before the constructor goes off? I really do not want to modify my class just so that I can test it because that breaks one of the golden rules of testing. My expectation is that when a controller that inherits from this base controller is instantiated, the "CurrentUser" property is automatically populated without the controller having to call a method to make it happen.

I understand that this could be implemented by lazy loading the property, but that would cause the authorization test to only happen if the property is used. I want the authorization test to happen every time the controller is instantiated regardless of whether or not the "CurrentUser" property is ever referenced.

Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated.

Comment: why not instantiate the base class ```var controller = new BaseController();``` and then just setting the property you need to be different to null as ```controller.CurrentUser = new UserInformation() {} ...```.

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion Rod. I could do it that way but I really want any derived classes to be able to access that property transparently. I do not want them to have to care about how the value was obtained.